# create react app how to serve it over https?

Tags: reactjs

Could someone point me to a link for total beginners as to how to set up https using create react app?

I've ejected the app and need to modify webpack I think.  But then I don't know where to go from there.

I have self-signed certificates generated already.

Thank you

Comment: locally over https or do you want to deploy it?

Comment: It's off topic for SO and even your question is unclear.

Comment: You should probably include the server tag as well in this question. Anyways, you need not bother ejecting it ( if build is your only use case ). All you need to do is `npm run build` on the server you are hosting it, and point a `dns` to the build folder. You'll be good to go

Comment: This should be handled by the web server and not the app itself. App should be protocol agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to modify your webpack or eject the app to use https

If you want to use Https in development you'll need to set the environment veriable HTTPS=true in your start script in package.json

> HTTPS=true npm start

read about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-https-in-development)

If you want to host it on something like amazon S3 you can use cloudfront

https://medium.com/@omgwtfmarc/deploying-create-react-app-to-s3-or-cloudfront-48dae4ce0af

Comment: @johnsam Yes i've deployed an app using s3 and cloudfront.

Comment: ah ok..  with https ?

Comment: thanks, I could not get it to work.  Serving it over https using https=true is not the same thing as adding a valid ssl certificate.  I'm trying to use a service worker which requires a real honest to goodness certificate.  not even self-signed will work.

Comment: @user798719 Do you want to test the app locally or are you looking to deploy it?